# Do check bonuses apply to passive checks?

Tags: dnd-4e, skills

The Warlord Class Feature *Canny Leader* grants a *"+2 bonus to Insight checks and Perception checks"* to you and allies within 10 squares.

Does this also apply to checks against Passive Perception and Passive Insight?

Comment: I'm think the passives are "modifiers" and not "checks", so the question is probably whether the Passives count as checks or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the compendium entry on [Vision and Light](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=312):

> If you aren’t actively searching an area, the DM determines whether you see hidden objects or creatures by using your passive Perception check.

So passives are checks, so yes, your Warlord grants you the bonus.